# Dropdown closing automatically in MatTable

Tags: angular, angular6

I have Mat Table that Renewed every 5 seconds as below.

```
ngOnInit() {
timerId = window.setInterval(() => {
    this.getAppLiveStreams(this.streamListOffset, this.pageSize);      
}, 5000);
}



getAppLiveStreams(offset: number, size: number): void {

        offset = offset * size;

        this.restService.getAppLiveStreams(this.appName, offset, size).subscribe(data => {
            this.broadcastTableData.dataRows = [];
            for (var i in data) {

                this.broadcastTableData.dataRows.push(data[i]);

            }
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.broadcastTableData.dataRows);
        });
       }
```

Also, I have a dropdown in the list as below

[image]

Dropdown closing when Dashboard is refreshed by the timer. I want to dropdown don't close when refreshed by the timer. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I will add as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: @SelimEmreToy How the html code looks like?

Comment: Please do share the service.ts file too

Comment: The same problem I have met. After refreshing the data source, the dropdown opened will close. I don't know any better ways to handle it.

Comment: @Neven.Leung Hi, I found my own solution. Can you please check in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with `clearInterval` method. Let me tell you in my solution:

When dropdown clicked, I'm stopping `timerId` and start `dropdownTimer`(It's starting 10-sec interval). DropdownTimer starting default `timerId` in 10 seconds later.

In my theory, 10 seconds is enough for the choose some actions. If there is no selection, close the dropdown or click any item in dropdown, default `timerId` will be starting in 10 seconds later.

Comment: In my app, I don't have any timers for closing dropdown. I only use RxJS's `timer` to update the data source of  mat-table in every 15 seconds. I am trying to figure out why updating the data source will reset the state of dropdown.

Comment: Even if the table data is the same,  the refresh of the data source will reset the state of dropdown.